# Material-ui: Set tab background color based on passed prop to a styledTab

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, mern

I have prepared this custom tab to style it as I want:

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const StyledTab = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
}))((props) => {
  const { shouldSetBackgroundColorToOrange } = props;
  return <Tab {...props} />;
});
```

This is how it's used:

```
<StyledTab label={"Room"} shouldSetBackgroundColorToOrange={true} />;
```

I'd like to set its color to orange based on the `shouldSetBackgroundColorToOrange` prop that's passed to it.

But, I couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below and in this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-darkness-5q0yt0?file=/demo.tsx:0-675)

In using the button but you can easily adopt it in your code

```
import React from "react";
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

interface styleProps {
  shouldSetBackgroundColorToOrange: boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: ({shouldSetBackgroundColorToOrange}: styleProps) =>
        shouldSetBackgroundColorToOrange ? "orange" : "yellow"
    }
  })
);

function TestComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles({ shouldSetBackgroundColorToOrange: true });
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" className={classes.root}>
     Button
    </Button>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;
```